# Sort order not being broken down

Tags: nosql, apache-phoenix

I'm trying to do a simple query where I want to order by Date, Hour, and score where the date and hour are coming from the same field (epoch_seconds).  I have accomplished this so far by the following:

```
SELECT cast(epoch_seconds as date) as d, hour(cast(epoch_seconds as time)) as t, score as s
FROM MyTable
order by cast(epoch_seconds as date), hour(cast(epoch_seconds as time)) desc, s asc
limit 10;
```

The issue I am running into is that when the date is there, it SEEMS to order by date and time, making the other sorts meaningless (since its down to the second)  I tested this by trying the following, and it works appropriately.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('1986-12-11') d, hour(cast(epoch_seconds as time)) as t, score as s
FROM MyTable
order by d, hour(cast(epoch_seconds as time)) desc, s asc
limit 10;
```

is there a way to sort by Date while ignoring the time?

Thanks

EDIT:

to prove my theory, I tried the the following

```
TO_CHAR(cast(epoch_seconds as date))
```

and it displays

```
2020-09-02 14:53:30.313
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring it out shortly after posting.

it ain't pretty, but this does the trick.

```
select subStr(TO_CHAR(cast(epoch_seconds as date)),0,10) as d,
       cast(epoch_seconds  as time) as t
From table
order by d, t
```